# drop-downs not working in Managed Metadata Navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-navigation, term-set

I'm trying to set up a Term-Store based Managed Metadata navigation for my site. I can create as many levels as I want in the term store, but only the top-level terms show in my navigation. I have each term in the navigation set to Simple Link or Header. Whether my header is blank or has a link in it, no drop-downs appear below it when I mouse over or click on it. I have publishing feature enabled on my site- the site is a SharePoint Online (O365) site that was just migrated from SP 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was some custom CSS that was interfering with the drop-downs. That has been resolved by the developer who built it and now it's working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test in my SharePoint online environment, I set up the Term-store for the managed metadata navigation.

Then if I configure the managed navigation for the site collection, the managed navigation can work fine.

And if I configure the managed navigation for the sub site, then the managed navigation cannot work.

You could check if the current site is the sub site.

Comment: I'm working at the root site in my site collection.

Comment: You could check if there is custom code in your site collection.

Comment: The problem it turns out was custom CSS that was blocking the drop-downs from appearing. That's been resolved and now they work just fine.

Comment: If the reply is helpful to you, you could accept it as answer.